# Powershell: convert XmlDocument to XmlNode

Tags: powershell

I was wondering if it was possible to convert an Xml Document into an Xml Node in PowerShell. So afterwards, I could get each property or even attach the node onto another Xml file.

I found 'Import-Clixml' but I get an error that I think I know how to fix, but I want to know if I can bypass that.

```
Import-Clixml : Element 'Objs' with namespace name 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/2004/04' was not found. Line 2, position 2.
At line:1 char:1
+ Import-Clixml .\FLSCHOBVWCGRB1.xml
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Import-Clixml], XmlException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Xml.XmlException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportClixmlCommand
```

---

EDIT:

Without converting `XmlDocument` and appending onto another `XmlDocument`

This is the PowerShell script I used:

```
$xml = New-Object XML
$xml.load('c:\Users\Acer\Desktop\big.xml')
$servers = Select-Xml -Xml $xml -XPath '//SERVERS'
$doc = [Xml](gc 'c:\Users\Acer\Desktop\node.xml')
$servers.Node.AppendChild($doc)
```

This is the error:

```
Exception calling "AppendChild" with "1" argument(s): "The specified node cannot be inserted as the valid child of this node, because the specified node is the wrong type."
At line:6 char:1
+ $servers.Node.AppendChild($doc)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
```

Comment: `XmlDocument` inherit from `XmlNode`, that means every `XmlDocument` is `XmlNode`, no conversion needed.

Comment: So, you can append/insert/prepend/etc. to another `XmlDocument`?

Comment: I does not see reasons, why you can not do that. Do you try any code? Did it throw exception or produce unexpected result?

Comment: Please see the edit. The code may be wrong. I'm new to this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to add node from one document to another, then you have to import it first:

```
$xml = New-Object XML
$xml.load('c:\Users\Acer\Desktop\big.xml')
$servers = Select-Xml -Xml $xml -XPath '//SERVERS'
$doc = [Xml](gc 'c:\Users\Acer\Desktop\node.xml')
$imported=$xml.ImportNode($doc.DocumentElement,$true)
$servers.Node.AppendChild($imported)
$xml.Save('c:\Users\Acer\Desktop\big2.xml')
```

Answer (score 5):

## Beware the *CliXML cmdlets

They pretty much set everyone up for failure.  Inevitably, everyone in their powershell career will stumble upon needing to import an XML document and try to use the `Import-CliXML` Cmdlet and get hosed.

The only reason to ever use these Cmdlets is to export and import objects from a PowerShell session and preserve their rich .Net type information.  Arguably, any time you'd need to use them, you could just as easily use `Import-/Export-CSV` instead as well.  So, if you were helping a friend troubleshoot some commands and he had variables that you needed to work with, he could export all of his variables using the `Export-CLIXml` cmdlets, and give them to you with his code.  You could then `Import-CLIXml` againsts them all and then you'd have roughly an equivalent environment to help troubleshoot.

That being said, the *CLIXml cmdlets are *not meant* to be used when you have an XML file to import.

**It's actually easy to import an XML file though :)**

If you'd like to import an XML document, the single easiest way is as follows:

```
$XMLDocument = [XML](Get-Content .\XMLFile.Xml)
```

This will instruct PowerShell to read the file with Get-Content, and to use it's built-in Casting and conversion methods to read it as an XML file.  It's surprisingly easy!

**Example**

Take this super simple XML document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<note>
   <to>Tove</to>
   <from>Jani</from>
   <heading>Reminder</heading>
   <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

Assuming it's named simple.xml, if we follow the steps I've given you, we'll end up with the following:

```
PS T:\> $XML = [xml](Get-Content .\simple.xml)
PS T:\> $XML

xml                                             note
---                                             ----
version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"                  note
```

We can then step into the properties by using PowerShell's nifty .Notation (pronounced 'Dot notation')  syntax.  So If I wanted to grab the body of the note, I'd just add on the property name like so.

```
PS T:\> $XML.note.body
Don't forget me this weekend!
```

I hope this helps, if you have any questions or would like help with accessing values from a very complex .XML document, please reply and post your source doc on something like PasteBin or wherever.

Comment: thank you for this post, I need to parse xml every year or so and I forget this issue and then have remember the real way to do xml in powershell.